# How to separate whole number and decimal number to two different variable

Tags: c++

I am  trying to separate whole number and decimal number 
two int variable

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double initialAmount = 42800.13;
    double fractionalPart = initialAmount - floor(initialAmount);
    cout<<int(initialAmount)<<"\n"<<fractionalPart<<"\n";

}
```

Present output is

```
42800
0.13
```

expected output

```
42800
13
```

It can be more than two decimal places .
any easy way to do that

Comment: What is the logic here? Why should `0.13` be mapped to `13` and not, say, `13000000000000001`, if your CPU decides that's how it looks in floating point? Put another way: How to decide how many places to keep, i.e. how many positions to show in the `int`? Do you have a specific epsilon in mind? You need to provide a far more detailed explanation of what you're trying to do, and how.

Comment: Convert it to string, remove first 2 characters, convert it back to int.  Probably the ugliest solution ever.

Comment: @SvSv: If it is always 2 characters, one can just multiple by 100 instead.  The problems is that the question doesn't give any rule for finding the number of digits in the fraction other than "it's magic".

Comment: @underscore_d  I can understand your broader way of thinking , but presently just need to remove the front  "." may be suggestion by sv sv is what I will have to do

Comment: btw you should use `std::modf()` instead of subtraction of `floor()`

Comment: Am I right to understand that you are not going to actually use the fraction int in any int-like fashion? I.e. the value is irrelevant? I.e. you are only interested in the character representation? In that case may I recommend to simply NOT convert it into int? Keep the string representation as proposed by Sv. I would consider that more purpose-matching and therefor more "clean".

Comment: Convert to string, look for .  Whole number is to left, fraction is to right.  As long as you are willing to live with rounding it works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, it could help to convert the number into a string.  Here's one possibility:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main() {
  double d = 42800.13;
  std::vector<std::string> numbers_s;
  std::string s; 
  std::istringstream numberAsString(std::to_string( d ));
  while (getline(numberAsString, s, '.')) {
    numbers_s.push_back(s);
  }
  std::cout << "whole number:" << numbers_s[0] << std::endl;
  //[ remove trailing zeros from fractional part:
  numbers_s[1].erase(numbers_s[1].find_last_not_of('0') + 1, std::string::npos);
  //]
   std::cout << "fractional part:" << std::stoi(numbers_s[1]) << std::endl;
}
```

Error checks should be added to capture cases when the number does not contain a decimal point.

Comment: Result comes whole number:42800
fractional part:130000
Program ended with exit code: 0

Comment: I do agree with you guys @RHertel M not judging anyone just trying to get some help . Trying to get best possible solution

Comment: @HariomSingh Edited the answer. Should be ok now.

Comment: added       std::cout << "fractional part:" << std::stoi(numbers_s[1]) << std::endl; for leading zero cases
  double d = 42800.001213;

Answer (score 4):

Maybe not the best solution, but at least it is simple :)

Store your `double` `initialAmount` in a `int` - which will truncate the decimal part. Then you have the number before the decimal point. Then subtract that from the initial value and you'll be left with just the part after the decimal point. Multiply that by however many powers of 10 that you deem significant and then again store that in a `int` and you'll have your two values.

Comment: seems trivial but can we just find decimal length and multiply