# finding ratio of a decimal

Tags: string, double, multiplication

I read that to find the ratio between two decimals I need to multiply both by powers of 10 until they are both whole numbers. then simplify the ratio.

my program is currently doing this

input:
9.902, 1.00131

ratio: 58247 : 5890

the ratio is not correct

when I debug it I realize that the computer store the numbers inaccurately

9.902 becomes 9.9019999999999992
1.00131 becomes 1.0013099999999999

thus the ratio becomes 58247 : 5890

I am thinking of converting them to strings and then move the decimals that way.
I am wondering if anyone has any better ideas?

Comment: Multiply each input value by a number to remove the decimal places.  In your example, 9.902 x 100,000 = 990,200 and 1.00131 x 100,000 = 100,131.  Find the greatest common factor of 990,200 and 100,131 to get the ratio.  Floating-point arithmetic will cause rounding errors.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47291283/how-to-separate-whole-number-and-decimal-number-to-two-different-variable I found this link that might help me as well